Why does Locale::acceptFromHttp give different result for same input?
I have a PHP (Symfony) project. This currently runs on fpm-alpine base, which all the files mounted in the /app dir.
I'm making a complete image, Nginx+phpFpm + the project in one go.
In the current project the locale is set to NL which is correct. My new neater version gives en-US. I've narrowed it down to the PHP native function Locale::acceptFromHttp, this gives different results, depending on the variant of website I view.
// Old: 
echo Locale::acceptFromHttp('nl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3'); // 'nl'
// New:
echo Locale::acceptFromHttp('nl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3'); // 'en-US

I have dug deep, even trying to see whatever the actual C code does, but I can't find why it would differ. Practically everything I verify is the same on both versions of the website, so the fact acceptFromHttp behaves like this, is odd to me.




Old version
image based version




PHP version
8.2
8.3


php intl module present
Yes
Yes


Nginx version
Unknown (but likely close)
1.26


ICU version
73.2
74.1


ICU Data version
73.2
74.1


ICU TZData version
2023c
2023c


ICU Unicode version
15.0
15.1



I dont have much details on the base image of the old version, that is made my the original builders who wont give access, but if I dive into the dockerfile it tell me they apk install icu-data-full, which I've added to my build to no avail.
How can it be it still differs? I doubt those small version differences mean anything. What else can I check/update? Both variants don't really do odd custom logic, both are pretty straight forward.
If there is something else I can do to give feedback, feel free to comment.

Control variable, can you check the result with ICU 73.2?

I switched to another ticket in the meanwhile, if I have a moment available I will see how hard that is to do :)

Quote manual: "Tries to find locale that can satisfy the language list that is requested by the HTTP "Accept-Language" header." - my interpretation of "tries to" would be that it tries to find a match among the locales installed on the system. On your new system it appears not to find a match for nl, so it moves on to the next preferred language, en-US.

I agree. But how to confirm?
